# Mismatching object type in Python in Colaboratory vs LeetCode

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a question.
I am solving this problem in LeetCode https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-intervals/

Below is my solution which works in my Python IDE (Google Colaboratory) but not in the LeetCode submission.

In Colaboratory Python3, The List of Lists supports indexing, comparison (by the first element of list), and so on.

Look at this code snippet:

```
def overlap(a,b):
  if b[0] >= a[0] and b[0] <= a[1]:
        return [a[0], max(a[1], b[1])]
  if a[0] >= b[0] and a[0] <= b[1]:
        return [b[0], max(b[1], a[1])]

  return False

def itemGrabber(listerson):
  print(type(listerson)) 
  return listerson[0]

def merge(intervals):
  if len(intervals) < 2: return intervals
  intervals.sort(key = itemGrabber)

  for i in range(len(intervals) - 2):
    r = overlap(intervals[i], intervals[i+1])
    if r != False:
      intervals[i] = r
      del intervals[i+1]
  return intervals    


intervals = [[1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]]


overlap(b,c)
merge(intervals)
intervals
```

This line:

```
print(type(listerson))
```

returns `<type 'list'>` in colaboratory
and
returns `<class 'precompiled.interval.Interval'>` in LeetCode.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Leetcode use a class to represent an Interval rather than a list.
Try to reset the answer to the default one, and you will see the definition:

```
# Definition for an interval.
# class Interval:
#     def __init__(self, s=0, e=0):
#         self.start = s
#         self.end = e
```

So you should use Interval rather than List in Leetcode.

EDIT:
For example, `a[0]` should be `a.start`.

Comment: You are completely correct. I totally ignored that comment. I thought Intervals was some actual class in Python!

Comment: Glad that can help. Interval is actually a customized structure like TreeNode or LinkNode.